# iOS Packaging Error with Adobe Air 4.0 & FlashBuilder

Tags: java, ios, air, adobe, osx-mavericks

I am trying to package an IOS Build using Air 4.0. I am currently running OSX 10.9.2. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the Error:

Error occurred while packaging the application:

```
      java.lang.Exception:
      ld: library not found for -lcrt1.o
      Compilation failed while executing : ld64


      at com.adobe.flexide.multiplatform.ios.launching.IOSLaunchHandler.doPackage(IOSLaunchHandler .java:704)
      at com.adobe.flexide.multiplatform.ios.launching.IOSLaunchHandler.launch(IOSLaunchHandler.ja va:255)
      at com.adobe.flexide.launching.multiplatform.MultiPlatformLaunchDelegate.launch(MultiPlatfor mLaunchDelegate.java:184)
      at com.adobe.flexide.launching.AbstractFlexLaunchDelegate.launch(AbstractFlexLaunchDelegate. java:244)
      at com.adobe.flexide.launching.AbstractFlexLaunchDelegate.launch(AbstractFlexLaunchDelegate. java:134)
      at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:854)
      at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:703)
      at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:928)
      at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1132)
      at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)

      eclipse.buildId=M20110909-1335
      java.version=1.6.0_65
      java.vendor=Apple Inc.
      BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=en_US
      Framework arguments:  -keyring /Users/dariustam/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation
      Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86_64 -keyring /Users/dariustam/.eclipse_keyring -consoleLog -showlocation
```

Comment: We need more information. What is your app doing? Can you build a blank app? Are you using an ANEs? Anything you can tell us will help. We can't guess at what is going on based on a seemingly generic error stack trace

Comment: Thanks for the response. The project is a multi platform game. It’s structured into separate projects, Canvas (Web), Android and iOS. The Canvas and Android builds work fine. The iOS build has been neglected for a while and I’m fixing it. A shared project contains all the shared functionality and is built in as3.

There are a few ANEs built for the iOS, but I have them all disabled. They are not packaged with the build and it still throws this error.

The iOS functionality has no custom functionality currently. I plan to add and test the ANEs once this packaging error is resolved.

Comment: Figured it out, needed to update from Adobe Air 4.0 to Adobe Air 13.0